# Spring - bean initialization argument - UnsatisfiedDependencyException - Cannot convert DataBean to Vector?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-data, spring-bean

I have two lists (type vector) and I want to pick one of them as an argument for a bean initialization. However, although directly pass a vector to the class "Helper" constructor works ("helper1" in below example), passing a hnc:data generated from a method will be considered as a Bean instead of Vector ("helper2" below). Details below. Is there an easy way to resolve this error? A.k.a. make helper2 working? Thanks,

- Setup:

-- java:

```
public class VectorPicker {
    @Produces
    public Vector chooseAVector(@("v1") v1, @("v2") v2) {
        return v1;
    }
}
```

-- xml:

```
<util:list id="vector1" list-class="java.util.Vector">
    <value>value1</value>
</util:list>
<util:list id="vector2" list-class="java.util.Vector">
    <value>value2</value>
</util:list>
<bean name="vectorPicker" class="com.amazon.class.path.VectorPicker" />
<hnc:data name="chosenVector" ref="vectorPicker" method="chooseAVector" >
    <property name="v1" ref="vector1" />
    <property name="v2" ref="vector2" />
</hnc:data>
```

- Application

-- java:

```
public class Helper {
    public Helper(Vector v) {...}
}
```

-- xml:

```
<bean id="helper1" class="com.amazon.class.path.Helper">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="vector1" />
</bean> # this is working fine

<bean id="helper2" class="com.amazon.class.path.Helper">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="chosenVector" />
</bean> # this is throwing error
```

-- Error message:

```
rg.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helper2' defined in class path resource [assembly/data/data.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [com.amazon.matrix.nestedcomponents.spi.bean.DataBean] to required type [java.util.Vector]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks really wierd. The only constructor of the `Helper` receives a `Vector` instance as a parameter. So why do you expect that it will work? The problem is that you're trying to pass a bean of a class `VectorPicker` or its method `chooseAVector` (sorry I am not so close familiar with an XML-style declarations). 
The first thing that comes into my mind is to declare another one constructor of the `Helper` class with required parameter. Something like this:

```
public class Helper {

    @Autowired
    public Helper(VectorPicker  picker) {...}
}
```

or this

```
public class Helper {

    public Helper(BiFunction<Vector, Vector, Vector>  supplier) {...}
}
```